# In Android how to make the executing thread wait, but the UI thread continue

Tags: android

I am developing a 2 player board game with button clicks for moves y the 2 players. When playing with the device, I want it to pause before executing performClick() otherwise the move is too quick. I tried

```
    try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);                 
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
  b.performClick();
```

I have an animation listener before this that sets the status value in a textbox,but that is not getting written in the textbox. Please let me know how to solve this problem.Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't block the main thread. Use a `Handler` instead:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private void deferPerformClick() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            b.performClick();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Woww awesome it worked!!! Thankyou!!  I added final Handler mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper()); inside the method because when I put it out, it gave an exception. it worked then. hope it won't give me a problem later. But thanks a million again!!!

Comment: It's not a good idea to make `Handler` a local variable. I've just updated the answer so it shouldn't cause a crash anymore.